# where is the source code for the which command?

Tags: command-line, source-code, coreutils

I looked around in coreutils, and did `sudo apt-cache search which`
I also looked at the manpages of which, I didn't find it.

I'd like to add an argument for listing dependencies to the executable, I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least on my Ubuntu 22.04, `/usr/bin/which` is provided by the `debianutils` package:

```
$ update-alternatives --list which
/usr/bin/which.debianutils
$ 
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/which.debianutils 
debianutils: /usr/bin/which.debianutils
```

It's a shell script - so no need to download the source:

```
$ file /usr/bin/which.debianutils 
/usr/bin/which.debianutils: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS `/usr/bin/which` is in the path for a normal (non-root) user:

```
$ which which
/usr/bin/which
```

And the above is a symbolic link:

```
$ file /usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/which: symbolic link to /bin/which
```

And the target is a shell script:

```
$ file /bin/which
/bin/which: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

And the shell script is provided by `debianutils`

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/which
debianutils: /bin/which
```

The above answer is a variation of the answer from steeldriver, showing Ubuntu 18.04 is slightly different from Ubuntu 22.04.

Under Ubuntu 18.04 `update-alternatives` is reporting an error for `which`:

```
$ update-alternatives --list which
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for which
```